# How to restart (Java) decompiler in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, decompiler

I am using:
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

and have installed de default Class Compiler:
-Procyon
-FernFlower
-JD-Core
-JAD

First of all: I DO see the RESULT (a decompiled File)

How is it possible to change these decompiler and see the new decompiled class?
It it possible to see any hint in the decompiled File which Decompiler was used to do the job?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How to use different decompilers in Eclipse? Why do you want to have different ones?

Comment: If you want to easily try out multiple decompilers, why not try https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer or https://github.com/helios-decompiler/Helios?